# Asp.net core webapi print to installed printers on server

Tags: printing, asp.net-core-webapi

my problem is i want to have a asp.net core web api and will send data that will be replaced in a .pdf file and should be printed to a network printer.

On Windows i created a winForm Application and it works very well!

i use [spire.PDF free](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-pdf-component.html) for that.

```
private void Print()
{
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
    pdf.LoadFromFile(filePathToPdfTemplate);
    PdfFormWidget? formWidget = pdf.Form as PdfFormWidget;
    pdf.PrintSettings.PrinterName = "MY PRINTER NAME";

    for (int i = 0; i < formWidget?.FieldsWidget.List.Count; i++)
    {
        PdfField? field = formWidget.FieldsWidget.List[i] as PdfField;

        if (field is PdfTextBoxFieldWidget)
        {
            PdfTextBoxFieldWidget textBoxField = field as PdfTextBoxFieldWidget;
            switch (textBoxField.Name)
            {
                case "val1":
                    textBoxField.Text = "my Value1";
                    break;
                case "val2":
                    textBoxField.Text = "my Value2";
                    break;
                case "val3":
                    textBoxField.Text = "my Value3";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    pdf.Print();
}
```

But how can i create a function that will get the installed printers on server *(where the asp.net core webApi is hosted by IIS)* and print the pdf to a network printer.

My idea was to create a service with the C# Function, but how can i pass the parameters?
or is there a better solution ?

thanks

Comment: There are many ways to pass the parameter, by form or by body or by query or by route. It depends on you. BTW, how do you call this api? What is your client?

Comment: hi, my problem is how can i creat an api that can access the server printers. But now iam on the way to learn WCF,. Thank you